# Laravel redirect to route with errors

Tags: laravel

I'm trying to redirect to a route with errors but the error is null, i don't know if I'm doing something wrong i have seen people online doing the same thing and saying it works so there might be something wrong with Laravel Configuration, although the code is like below:

```
if ($status=='CANCELED'){
                            $error_msg = trans('book.payment_error_canceled');
                        } else if ($status=='REFUSED') {
                            $error_msg = trans('book.payment_error_refused');
                        } else {
                            $error_msg = trans('book.payment_error_general');
                        }
                
    return redirect()->route('book.step.four')->with('error', $error_msg);
```

This goes to this controller function: tried(`dd(session('error')`) is null

```
public function stepFour(Request $request)
    {
  
        $cart = Session::get('cart');

        if(!(isset($cart['service_id']) && isset($cart['location_id']) && isset($cart['schedule_id']))){
            return redirect()->route('book.index');
        }

        $service     = CalendarService::find($cart['service_id']);
        $location    = CalendarPlace::find($cart['location_id']);
        $schedule    = CalendarSchedule::find($cart['schedule_id']);

        return view('book.step_four', compact('location', 'service', 'schedule', 'cart')); 
    }
```

And then in view not showing and null:

```
    @if (session('error'))
        <div class="alert alert-danger">
            <ul>
                <li>{{ session('error') }}</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    @endif
```

Laravel Version: 5.8

Comment: what is not working?

Comment: @lagbox Updated question to make it more clear, basically the error is null and i can't display the error.

Comment: @EmekaMbah I commented that earlier, but removed it; `session()->put('error', 'test')` followed by `session('error')` return `'test'`, `session()->has('error')` is `true`, and `session()->get('error')` is `'test'`; in this case, `session('error')` is enough, since `trans()` cannot return a false-y value (`trans('book.payment_error_canceled')` returns `'book.payment_error_canceled'` if the Translation isn't set, etc.)

Comment: @EmekaMbah Nope: https://i.stack.imgur.com/8IMZL.png (and for additional proof: `session('test') == session()->has('test') && session('test') == session()->get('test')` returns `true`)

Comment: great point. I got it.